# Slightly larger file sizes when using SWC in Next JS

Tags: next.js, swc-compiler

Updating a Next js project to use SWC over Babel, no problems building the project but all the files are slightly larger (2-10kb).

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    compiler: {
        reactRemoveProperties: { properties: ['^data-cy$'] }
    },
    swcMinify: true,
}
```